# Pulling content for weekly data

Tags: sql

I have been tasked for pulling data, but only for each week. The count needs to restart each Monday and ends that Friday.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS PieceCount 
FROM SmallPaintTransferConveyorFloat
```

Comment: Which dbms? Date/time handling is too often not ANSI SQL compliant...

Answer (score 2):

[DATEPART](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp) allow you to filter by week

If you have a column with the date in your table you can use :

```
SELECT count(*) AS PieceCount
FROM SmallPaintTransferConveyorFloat
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, <date_column_name>), DATEPART(year, <date_column_name>)
```

Replace the 2nd parameter with the correct column name on your table

Here's a short sqlfiddle example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a92ad/4/0

**EDIT**

Add DATEPART(year, date_column_name) to remove unwanted merge if data cover more than a year

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It worked, but it is giving me two totals. One looks to be everything before today, and the second is today. How do I just show today and then the rest of this week?

Comment: I add a sqlfiddle link where it works... can you give a list of date in your table to test why it don't work for you ?

Comment: Also if your data are going over 1 year you'll have some unwanted merge... so you may add group by datepart(year, <date_column_name>) as 2nd group by filter